# Layout changes using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to make a full screen app for my Raspberry Pi. I got the code working to a degree. All I want to do now is split the top red section into 3 parts which I can put labels in containing data that will frequently change.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Number Bonds!")

test = StringVar(value="XX + XX = XXX")
score = StringVar(value="0")
question = StringVar(value="7/10")
time = StringVar(value="8s")


w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

topFrame = Frame(root, bg="red", width=w, height=h/4)
##Label(topFrame, text="test").grid(row=1, column=1)
topFrame.pack()

bottomFrame = Frame(root, bg="blue", width=w, height= h-(h/4))
bottomFrame.pack()

equation = Label(bottomFrame, textvariable=test, font=("Arial", 70))
equation.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

[This is what I have, and the bottom how I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W45KO.png)

But when I add the commented line it looks like this:

[It all breaks - Removed]

How can I get 3 equal size boxes at the top with labels in them?!

EDIT:

I must have just been too tired and stupid to think about this and got caught up in the fact the boxes "HAD" to be the same size. After a few minutes of code changes from the original above, I ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Number Bonds!")

test = StringVar(value="XX + XX = XXX")
score = StringVar(value=999)
question = StringVar(value="10/10")
time = StringVar(value="10")


w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

topFrame = Frame(root, bg="red", width=w, height=h/4)

##Score
scoreTextLabel = Label(topFrame, text="Score: ", font=("Arial", 30))
scoreTextLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

Label2 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=score, font=("Arial", 30))
Label2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,50))

##Question
qTextLabel = Label(topFrame, text="Question: ", font=("Arial", 30))
qTextLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

TextLabel2 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=question, font=("Arial", 30))
TextLabel2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,50))

##Time
tTextLabel = Label(topFrame, text="Time: ", font=("Arial", 30))
tTextLabel.pack(side=LEFT)

TextLabel3 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=time, font=("Arial", 30))
TextLabel3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=(0,50))


topFrame.pack(pady=(0,120))

bottomFrame = Frame(root, bg="blue", width=w, height= h-(h/4))
bottomFrame.pack()

equation = Label(bottomFrame, textvariable=test, font=("Arial", 70))
equation.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

[Which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0e8D.png)

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Do you want the top frame to stay its original size no matter what is inside the frame? By default frames will shrink or grow to fit their contents, which is usually the best behavior for a GUI.

Comment: Yes, the width it is now I want it to stay like that but with 3 other labels in it, all of equal width.

Comment: What about the height? Do you want a fixed height, or just tall enough to contain the labels?

Comment: Tbh, now I think about it, it doesn't really matter? As long as the equation is as bold as it can be and takes up the whole width of the screen, I can increase the font size of the labels if need be and add padding to separate them out?

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to configure the top row so it shows, and uses sticky to stretch the frame so it occupies the entire space, and uses a set width for the Label as well.  You might also want to increase the font size of the label if you want the type to be larger.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Learning Number Bonds!")

test = StringVar(value="XX + XX = XXX")
score = StringVar(value="0")
question = StringVar(value="7/10")
time = StringVar(value="8s")


w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

topFrame = Frame(root, bg="red", width=w, height=h/4)

## put an empty row on top
topFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=100)
Label(topFrame, text="test", bg="lightblue", width=50).grid(row=1,     column=1)
topFrame.grid(sticky="nsew")

bottomFrame = Frame(root, bg="blue", width=w, height= h-(h/4))
bottomFrame.grid(row=1)

equation = Label(bottomFrame, textvariable=test, font=("Arial", 70))
equation.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand why the second part (XX + ...) has now reduced in width? http://puu.sh/ohfK3/b5abd131f3.png

Comment: I changed the second frame to grid() from pack() so now everything in the column is the same width.

Comment: Thank very much for your help but I think I was just too tired at the time and have now got it working with little more then padding. I will update my post.